# Labeling the vertices of a graph

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I would like to label the vertices of a complete graph alphabetically.

But I am stuck because I don't know how to associate only one vertex to a letter.

```
y = {Before, After, Below, Above, Below, Above}

CompleteGraph[6, EdgeStyle -> {_ <-> 2 -> Red, Thickness[0.01]}, 
VertexSize -> 0.1, VertexLabels -> Placed[{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, y]]
```

[image]

I would appreciate any suggestion or help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = 6;  

c = CharacterRange["a", "z"][[;; n]];

labels = Table[i -> Style[c[[i]], 15, Bold], {i, n}];

CompleteGraph[n,
 EdgeStyle -> {_ <-> 2 -> Red, Thickness[0.01]}, 
 VertexSize -> 0.1,
 VertexLabels -> labels]
```

[image]

**Update**

Variable label placement

```
y = {Before, After, Below, Above, Below, Above};

labels = Table[i -> Placed[Style[c[[i]], 15, Bold], y[[i]]], {i, n}];
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see now what I did wrong. But how can I change the position of the labels, e.x. "b" to be placed **Before** the vertex or "c" to be placed **Below**? Again, thank you.

Comment: See updated answer